# $LSB_JOBID variable not picking up any value in LSF system

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

I have script that loops through certain kinds of files and sends it to another script as follows:

```
   for i in folder_a/*_.txt; do
./trial.sh $i   
   done
```

The trial.sh takes the file parameter and has following code:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 file=${1}
 f=${ar[$LSB_JOBID ]}
 echo $f
```

I am unable to output the variable f, so I am kind of wondering if there is something I need to add.

Comment: try to echo `$LSB_JOBID`. Also you never explained how the `ar` array is populated.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov when I echo $LSB_JOBID it gives out nothing

Comment: Are you sure you are running this script with `bsub` or `lsrun` command? To use `LSB_JOBID` variable your script needs to run in the context of an LSF job.

Comment: Oh I was running it as a shell script, let me try running it with the LSF commands